# Is there a UMVUE for arbitrary distribution with density and variance?

Tags: estimators, unbiased-estimator, optimal

Let F be the family of all distributions with probability density and finite variance, and $X_1, ..., X_n$ be random samples from F.

Does UMVUE for variance exists for this situation?

Comment: Do you mean UMVUE of any function $g(\theta)$ where the family $F$ is parametrised by $\theta$ or the UMVUE of $\text{Var}(X_i)$ in particular?

Comment: I meant the UMVUE for Var(X). For example the sample variance is umvue for variance (simga^2) when the family is normal distribution with arbitrary mean and variance, and I was trying to generalize it.